# Can you please correct me if i am wrong about REST?

Tags: rest

REST is used to communicate any two systems.

So that if you want get info from one machine we have to use GET method and add info in one system we need to use the method POST..Like wise PUT and DELETE.

When a machine GETs the resource, it will ask for the machine readable one. When a browser GETs a resource for a human, it will ask for the human readable one.

So When you are sending request from machine 1. It will go to some machine x. Machine x will send a machine readable format to machine 1. Now Browser changes to user readable format.

So JSON is a machine readable format and HTML is a client readable format...Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: JSON can be interpreted by a machine, and HTML can be rendered into a human-friendly form by a browser, that's true. I'm not sure what this necessarily has to do with REST, though.

Answer (score 3):

REST is an architectural style, not a technology. That being said, the only technology that most people know that is intended to align with the REST architectural style is HTTP. If you want to understand the REST architectural style, I recommend the following two resources:

- Roy Fielding's presentation "The Rest of REST" (http://roy.gbiv.com/talks/200709_fielding_rest.pdf)
- The book "RESTful Web Services"

When you send a GET request for a resource, it is up to the server to determine what representation (format, e.g. html vs. json) it wishes to send back. The client can send along an Accept header that specifies a set of preferred formats, but it's ultimately up to the server to decide what it wants to send. To learn more about this interaction, Google on "HTTP content negotiation".

The reason browsers tend to get back HTML is that they send an Accept header with "text/html". If you somehow configured your browser to always send an Accept header of only "application/json", you would sometimes get JSON back (if the server supported JSON representations), sometimes HTML (if the server ignored your Accept header) and sometimes an error saying that the server could not support the representation you requested.

A computer can parse either JSON or HTML if you have the right libraries. JSON content tends to be structured data (optimized for parsing) and HTML tends to be optimized for presentation, so JSON is generally much easier for a program to parse.

Comment: Can you tell me that REST ensures that what?  Is it meant by that when you send request to resource it is responding properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right to me. HTML is definitely for end-user consumption (despite all the nasty screen-scraping code out there) and there's no way that I'd want to deliver JSON (or XML or YAML) to end-user clients for direct display.

You probably want to ensure that you only deliver HTML that matches up with the same basic data model that you're delivering to mechanical clients; producing XHTML on demand by applying an XSLT stylesheet to an XML version of your standard responses is probably the easiest way to do it since it's likely you can do that with a layer that's independent of your basic application.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say "there's no way that I'd want to deliver JSON (or XML or YAML) to clients"?

Comment: @DOK: Ugh, yes. Done. You know how sometimes you can't see that something is really bad until someone points it out to you and then it's really obvious? That's just happened to me.

Comment: glad to help. That's exactly what I thought happened. If you come back and delete your commend in the next few minutes, I'll delete mine, as there seems to be no real purpose in leaving them here,eh?

Comment: Hi Donal,  Can you tell me REST ensures what? Is it meant by that when you send request to resource it is responding properly or not? For this Purpose only are we using REST Testing?

Answer (score 0):

To be pedantic, both HTML and JSON are machine readable formats.  The difference is that HTML has a specification that describes some semantics that web browsers know how to interpret in order to visually render it.  The JSON spec has really no semantics other than defining how to serialize arrays, objects and properties.

Don't forget JSON and HTML are just two of the hundreds of potentially useful media type formats that a RESTful system can use.